# Azure pipelines working directory pointing two different places

Tags: bash, azure, azure-devops

Hi Everyone I have a question related to the pipeline.workspace variable.

In the example below i have set **pipeline.workspace** as the working directory and as paths for a cli command.

Npm install creates folders under **/home/vsts/work/node_modules/**
while the next command when i use pipeline.workspace it points to **./home/vsts/work/1/**

Am I doing something wrong? or is something up?

```
     - task: Bash@3
          displayName: 'Publish Sentry'
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |                  
              npm install @sentry/cli                                  
              .$(Pipeline.Workspace)/node_modules/.bin/sentry-cli releases --org --project new "$(Build.BuildNumber)" --finalize                      
            workingDirectory: "$(Pipeline.Workspace)"
```

Comment: Hi @Marcom, how are things going? Are the explanation and suggestion in my answer helpful to you? Please have a check with it. Feel free to tell us if you have any question about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **node_modules** folder is pre-generate that may contains some global packages. It is not generated by the `npm install` command in the script. This situation exists on Microsoft-hosted Ubuntu agents and Microsoft-hosted macOS agents.

When executing the `npm install` command to install packages locally, there are few points you need to pay attention to :

1. If no **node_modules** folder is existing in current working directory, and also no **node_modules** folder is existing in any parent directory of current working directory, the `npm install` command will generate the **node_modules** folder in current working directory and install the packages into this **node_modules** folder.
2. If no **node_modules** folder is existing in current working directory, but the **node_modules** folder is existing in parent directory, the `npm install` command will install the packages into the existing **node_modules** folder in the closest parent directory.

   For example, there are the following paths:

   - **/root/dir1/node_modules**
   - **/root/dir1/dir2/node_modules**
   - **/root/dir1/dir2/dir3**

   When executing the `npm install` command in the directory "**/root/dir1/dir2/dir3**", the packages will be installed into "**/root/dir1/dir2/node_modules**".
3. If the **node_modules** folder is existing in current working directory, regardless of whether the **node_modules** folder is existing in parent directory or not, the `npm install` command will install the packages into **node_modules** folder in current working directory.

   For example, there are the following paths:

   - **/root/dir1/node_modules**
   - **/root/dir1/dir2/node_modules**
   - **/root/dir1/dir2/dir3/node_modules**

   When executing the `npm install` command in the directory "**/root/dir1/dir2/dir3**", the packages will be installed into "**/root/dir1/dir2/dir3/node_modules**".

Comment: Yes that was helpful thank you. In the end change the npm install command to save to a specific folder.